# Keyboard not working after switching user in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

My PC is a custom built desktop machine. I had used Windows 7, 8, 8.1 on this machine without much issues. For past several months I've been using Windows 10 Pro x64. It was a fresh install. From about last 1 month I've been annoyed by a weird keyboard problem. Here is when it occurs:

- User X is using PC with User X Windows local account for some time (30+ minutes).
- User account switched to User Y (also local account).
- User Y can enter password to get access to his/her account.
- User Y logs into the PC.
- Keyboard stops working!

PC needs to be restarted to make the keyboard work again.

I believe some Windows update did something bad to the OS for this annoyance to happen. So I've been waiting for Microsoft to fix the bug but may be they are not aware of it yet or don't care I don't know.

Is there any known permanent solution to this problem? I'm experiencing same problem with 2 different desktop PCs running Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: Is this a wireless keyboard?

Comment: @Tim: one of them is wireless, the other one is USB-wired. the device drivers are updated.

Comment: You have them both in at once?

Comment: @Tim: No. I have two different desktop PCs running Windows 10. Both of them show this annoyance. In one PC the keyboard is wireless. In another one, it's wired.

Comment: If you have recently installed some program when you log in User Y? Recall or see on the programs list which one could be the most recent that caused this issue.

Comment: @Phoebeli: No, that's not the case I can assure you. I haven't installed any new software recently that could cause this problem.

Comment: Its very interesting that it is on both computers with the same user.
Perhaps a corrupted profile?
backup documents only, no settings, delete the folders, and delete the user from registry. Recreate the user.

Comment: @Tim: No. It's not for the same users. It happens for all users.

Comment: Same issue here. Filter keys option is off. Are you using a Steelseries Apex keyboard by any chance?

Comment: @akpe: no. filter keys are off. on one pc the keyboard is a USB, on another pc the keyboard is wireless.

Comment: Are you still suffering with the issue? If so try removing drivers from all your user and add them individually in every user and this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Filter keys. Check accessibility options to see if you have it enabled along with any other features related to the keyboard.
Check out when you first logon and when the keyboard stops working.

To check if this is the issue, somewhere where you can type, hold a key for a second. if it shows up your have filter keys turned on.

Comment: no, filter keys are turned off on the pc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing keyboard to a USB 2.0 input solved my issue. It was on a USB 3.0 port before

Comment: I would likely be best to edit your previous answer.