# Wired Keyboard not working after switching users in Windows 10

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard, user-switching

On my desktop computer running an up-to-date Windows 10 x64, my keyboard will stop working when I log in as any user, work for a while, and then switch to any other user. On the login screen, the keyboard is still working and I can type the password; but once the second user is logged in, the keyboard is dead. The problem is not related to filter keys, which are off.

Restarting the computer brings the keyboard back to life. Physically unplugging the keyboard and plugging it back in (even into the same USB port) also resolves the problem, but is of course annoying.

In order to make it easier to unplug the keyboard, I switched to plugging the keyboard into the front panel of my case (a be!quiet DARK BASE PRO 900 rev. 2) - which made the problem disappear.

I have tried all the USB ports on the back panel, and all of them cause the problem. Only the front panel works reliably. While this is workable, the idea of the front panel is not really to dedicate one of the ports to the keyboard.

What could the difference be? I first thought the front panel was USB2.0, but all ports are USB3, and so should all be using the same driver.

Is there a way to limit a specific back panel port to USB2.0, to check if that solves the problem?

Note: The problem is quite similar to the one described [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1019582/keyboard-not-working-after-switching-user-in-windows-10/) (which I cannot reply to due to being a newly registered user).

Comment: Though you might try disabling and then re-enabling the errant  USB port from Device Manager, or make a script to do so, I'd use a hardware hack: open the case and solder  a USB extension cable to the front port pins so it comes out the back.

Comment: That is a very pragmatic solution that might do it. No need to solder, though - I still have one USB3 and two USB2 pin headers available on the board and can just buy a standard USB slot bracket.

Comment: Thanks, I'd done that on an ancient desktop (Pentium, Win95) that had lost rear USB ports.

Comment: To give an update - I have added the slot bracket, and for the most part, the keyboard is working now. Strangely enough, about once every two weeks, the problem still reoccurs, but that is manageable...